# Converting C# list to javascript array

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, foreach

I have a SelectList from my C# Controller method that contains 8 text/value pairs. I would like to convert this to a JavaScript array that I can access in a foreignKey column of a kendo grid. The structure of my arObjArray is ok as expected. The only problem is the content of the array is wrong. Instead of having a list of 8 pairs consistent with the packageList item, I get an array of 8 rows with each row having the same value as the very last item in packageList. The relevant section of my javascript function is like this:

```
var arObjArray = [];
var arObj = {};

@foreach (SelectListItem d in packageList)
{
    @:arObj["text"] = "@d.Text";
    @:arObj["value"] = Number("@d.Value");

    @:arObjArray.push(arObj);
}
console.log(arObjArray)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: JavaScript will pass objects by reference - instead of declaring `arObj` outside the loop, declare it inside, or just push an object directly from inside the loop. `@:arObjArray.push({text: "", value: ""})`

Comment: You should use JSON.

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but I've never seen the syntax `@foreach`, `@:arObj`, etc before. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Klaycon ASP.Net MVC Razor (CSHTML files).

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed *by reference*, the same as instances in C#. In your foreach loop you are actually reusing the same object over and over, because it is only assigned to an empty object once (`var arObj = {};` outside the loop). Thus you're pushing *one* object to the array multiple times, and modifying the values of that one object each array iteration.

Declare and assign `arObj` inside the loop instead:

```
@foreach (SelectListItem d in packageList)
{
    var arObj = {};
    @:arObj["text"] = "@d.Text";
    @:arObj["value"] = Number("@d.Value");

    @:arObjArray.push(arObj);
}
```

Comment: tymeJV's suggestion did it. Not sure which Internet post I got the @foreach, @:arObj from.